# Max Date for each entry

Tags: sql, oracle, date, max

I'm rather new to SQL and I'm trying to query something that has a lot of duplicates, so I'm getting a lot of dates but I only want 1 of each entry and I'm struggling as to how to do that.

This is an example query of what I have, I'm not sure how to get the result I'm looking for from here though.

```sql
select 
    product_id,
    max(date_ordered)
    from products
```

Update: I've tried Group By as well but there are still duplicate products in the list since there are multiple dates. How do I only list 1 product with the most recent date ordered?

Update: Group by finally ended up working, thanks for those that suggested it. User error.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY`!

Comment: Also, I usually have plural table names, and singular column names. Like table products, with the column product.

Comment: @jarlh I tried Group by date ordered and products, it still has duplicate products in the list. How do I remove those?

Comment: You only want the max date, so don't group by that column.

Comment: @jarlh when I tried that I got an error message
`
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 63 Column: 11
`

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: @RoMEoMusTDiE Can you help me out with those? I'm not familiar with how to use any of them yet.

Comment: _"Also, I usually have plural table names, and singular column names"_  In addition, I _strongly_ recommend that _column_ names be in the format "adjective_noun".  Not only making names a bit more 'self-documenting', it also eliminates the possibility of using a key or reserved word, and/or duplicating the table name.  (Does "PRODUCTS" refer to the table or the column?  For OP's table, columns would be PRODUCT_ID, and ORDER_DATE.

Comment: @EdStevens thanks for the information, above is just a rough example of what I'm trying to accomplish, the query is more complicated in actuality but even this basic query doesn't work as I'd want so I'm trying to understand it even this basic example of how to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to use group by ,you have the documentation here  : https://sql.sh/cours/group-by

Comment: Can you show your data table, and the query that gives this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id,max(date_ordered)
from products
group by product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried Group by date ordered and products, it still has duplicate products in the list.

Use `GROUP BY` on the `product_id` column (and not on the `date_ordered` column):

```sql
SELECT product_id,
       max(date_ordered)
FROM   products
GROUP BY product_id;
```